# Permission denied error when pinging inside Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have just installed Docker on Ubuntu 18.04, and I cannot get access to outside networks from within my container.

I ran `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:trusty ping 192.168.1.1` which yields:
`socket: Permission denied`

On the other hand, the command `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:trusty whoami` yields `root` as expected, meaning the problem occurs inside the container.

How can I debug this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting AppArmor fixed the problem:

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove apparmor`

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation about why this worked.

Comment: This is a horrible suggestion, as it will weaken your systems default security by a great deal. DO NOT DO THIS if not fully certain what you are doing. Consider adding AppArmor rules instead.